# What is the difference between insertDefinition and and importAttribute in Apache Tiles?

Tags: apache-tiles

What is the difference between `tiles:importAttribute` and `tiles:insertDefinition` in Apache Tiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImportAttribute put a tiles attribute (from the current definition) and puts it into the request scope. (Tiles attributes, regardless of their type, are not normally available from the request scope).
eg

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="prefix"/>
<c:out value="${prefix}"/>
```

While insertDefinition is more for when you want to define a whole definition from within jsp (instead of having that definition defined in xml). Definitions can for example be built on-the-fly this way.
http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tagreference.html#tiles:insertDefinition